# how to handle the padding when brush moving

Tags: d3.js

I encountered a problem when using d3.brush.[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17sNt.png)
The graph is outside the limit.

related code(var xScale is for the bigger graph and xScale_ is for the graph which has a brush):

```
  var template = {
    width: '1200',
    height: '520',
    padding: 20,
    xScaleTick: 50,
    yScaleTick: 20
  };

 function initScale(dataset) {
    xScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([1, dataset[dataset.length - 1]['chapter']])
      .range([template.padding, template.width -  2*template.padding]);

    xAxis = d3
      .axisBottom()
      .scale(xScale)
      .ticks(template.xScaleTick);
  }

xScale_ = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([1, dataset[dataset.length - 1]['chapter']])
  .range([template.padding, template.width - 2 * template.padding]);

xAxis_ = d3
  .axisBottom()
  .scale(xScale_)
  .ticks(template.xScaleTick);

   var brush = d3
  .brushX()
  .extent([[xScale_(1), 0], [timeline.width, timeline.height]])
  .on('brush', brushed);

$timeline
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'brush')
  .call(brush)
  .call(brush.move, xScale_.range().map(value => value / 2));

 function brushed() {

    var s = d3.event.selection || xScale_.range();
    var smap = s.map(xScale_.invert,xScale_);
    xScale.domain(smap).nice();

    xAxis = d3
      .axisBottom()
      .scale(xScale)
      .ticks(template.xScaleTick);
    $chart
      .selectAll('g.area')
      .select('path')
      .attr('d', area)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + template.padding + ',0)');
    $chart.select('g.x').call(xAxis);
  }
```

I think maybe I have made the graph's padding in a wrong way,but I don't know how to fix it.
Thanks for any help.Or any related examples will be helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example: [Zoomable Area](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254)

You can define a `clipPath` to crop the graph to the area you wish. Code from the example:

```
var areaPath = g.append("path")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue");

g.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better solution. I just appended a "rect" to overlap the part out of the limit.
Sorry for my poor English.